# How do I @Autowire to an extended class when @Qualifier is used in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations

I have the following classes:

```
public class Service
{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(Helper.BEAN_NAME)
    protected Helper helper;
...
}

@Component(Helper.BEAN_NAME)
public class Helper
{
    public static final String BEAN_NAME = "Helper";
    ...
}

@Component(Helper.BEAN_NAME)
public class ExtHelper extends Helper
{
    ...
}
```

My goal is to not touch the Service or Helper classes. My thinking is that by giving ExtHelper the same bean name as Helper, Spring will autowire ExtHelper implementation to Service instead of Helper.

I am seeing mixed results with this. If ExtHelper is included in my pom AFTER Helper, it works ok. But before, I get a ConflictingBeanDefinitionException. I understand the exception, but not why I get it if I swap the order of dependencies in the POM.

My basic question is whether I am doing this correctly conceptually. Is @Qualifier intended to prevent this kind of override of autowiring? If not, what is the rule to make Spring resolve the conflict by choosing my extension over the base class? Am I required to extend the Service class to get what I want? I am new to Spring and don't quite get how I am *supposed* to be doing this.

Answer (score 1):

`@Qualifier` is intended to be used to instruct Spring which bean should be injected in case of multiple beans of type available.

In your case you have two beans that could be injected into `protected Helper helper` attribute so you have to tell Spring which one should be used. You can't do it with `@Qualifier` as both of the beans have the same name.

If you don't want to touch those classes you could use another annotation to prioritise a bean - `@Primary`. Add it on `ExtHelper` and it will be treated as a preferred bean in case of multiple bean available for injection.

If you want to stay with `@Qualifier` you would need to change name of one of those beans and inject preferred bean:

```
@Component
public class Service
{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("extHelper")
    protected Helper helper; // instance of Helper or ExtHelper could be injected here
    ...
}

@Component // bean will be named using default naming strategy: helper. You can obviously use your own name
public class Helper
{
    ...
}

@Component // bean will be named using default naming strategy: extHelper. You can obviously use your own name
public class ExtHelper extends Helper
{
    ...
}
```